# Using a regular expression to extract substring

Tags: regex, r

I'm trying to extract a substring in R, using `stringr`. Some timeago I wrote a script that did the job, however it does not work anymore. Probably due to an update, but I don't know.

My string looks like(!) this: `myStr <- "    layout = (3,3); //lala"`.
The string will always contain the `layout` keyword, the equal sign and the two braces (open ... close). However, the number of arguments in between can vary: (1,23,455,22) would also be possible. After the part after `)` can varying as well.

I like to obtain the substring starting form `(` and ending with `)`. Thus this example must give: `(3,3)`. Others may give e.g. `(1,23,455,22)`.

Up to now I used this:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract("    layout = (3,3); //lala", "*\\(.*\\)")
```

However this does not work anymore. It gives me this error:

```
Error in stri_extract_first_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = attr(pattern,  : 
  Syntax error in regexp pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX)
```

It used to work in the past. What is wrong this the regular expression?

**EDIT:**
If by string contains two pair of braces, the substring should select the left pair (the other is commented-out with `//`):

```
Str <- "layout = (1,2,3,4) //lala(huhu)"
gsub(".*([(])(.*)([)]).*", "\\1\\2\\3", Str)
#gives "(huhu)" which is not good; should be (1,2,3,4)
```

Comment: what language are you wrting this in?

Comment: You can use `strsplit` to split the column with `"(", ")"` and extract the middle one. Just a thought.

Comment: Try  `str_extract(Str,"\\([0-9,]+\\)")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex `"*\\(.*\\)"` is not correct as it starts with `*`, a quantifier, and that causes the incorrect regex syntax issue as you cannot have multiple string start positions (it is a logical error checked by the regex engine when parsing the expression).

> The substring should select the left pair

Use lazy matching in the left part - `.*?`:

```
myStr <- "layout = (1,2,3,4) //lala(huhu)"
gsub(".*?(\\([^()]*\\)).*", "\\1", myStr)
##    ^^^
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/O86BYy)

Result: `[1] "(1,2,3,4)"`

Lazy matching will ensure we match as few characters as possible before the first occurrence of the subsequent pattern.

Note that if you want to extract multiple `(number,number....)` values, you need to use

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(Str,"\\(\\d+(\\s*,\\d+)*\\)")
```

See the [regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/hN1eR1/2).

Comment: yes, it is. thank you - and also the others. worked very well.

Answer (score 2):

If the numbers and commas along with the parentheses needs to be extracted, use those patterns,

```
str_extract(Str,"\\([0-9,]+\\)")
#[1] "(1,2,3,4)"

str_extract(myStr,"\\([0-9,]+\\)")
#[1] "(3,3)"
```